# How to evaluate a boolean in Google Data Studio using CASE

Tags: google-data-studio

I am importing data from a spreadsheet with contains many columns, two of which are `Address` (which returns the URL of the page) and `Canonical Link Element 1` (which returns the canonical URL).

I wish to do a simple Boolean for whether or not the Address field and Canonical Field are the same so I can do a simple pie chart showing the percentage of Canonical URLs and Non-canonical URLs.

After reading the documentation on the `CASE`function, I tried the following formula:

`CASE WHEN Address = Canonical Link Element 1 THEN 'Canonical Page' ELSE 'Non-Canonical Page' END`

But I am unable to get this formula to work.

[image]

Comment: To the close voters: There are only 11 questions on [SO] flagged with `google-data-studio`.  Could someone explain why this would be on-topic there versus here?

Comment: @jonca It is relatively new software, but I purposely choose this Stack Exchange website because it seemed most consistent with the Google Suite of Products i.e. [google-spreadsheets].

Comment: I agree.  I have voted to leave it open here.